# Can a pointer returned by new have the same value as a deleted pointer returned by a previous use of new

Tags: c++, heap-memory

Will both the cout statement always print the same value?

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int* p = new int();
    *p = 54;
    cout<<p;    // it displays the address of int in heap();


    delete(p);
    p = new int[4];
    cout<<p;    // it displays the address of first block of memory, of array in heap;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `new int` vs. `new int[1]`?

Comment: Hint: Addresses of pointers *do not* change unless you change the pointer itself. Dereferencing it does not alter the pointer.

Comment: yes , sort of that

Comment: What happened when you tried this code? What did you learn?

Comment: Tip: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is a non-standard method of including header files, you should instead include exactly what you need. Additionally, `using namespace std` is a bad habit to get into, and should be avoided. The `std::`prefix serves a useful purpose.

Comment: The question in your title does not match that in the body.  Nothing is being "_overridden_" here, overwritten or reassigned perhaps.

Comment: Not necessarily. You've freed the old memory so the array created via `new[]` could reuse the memory freed previously, but the standard doesn't require `new` or `new[]` to return any specific memory.

Comment: I've improved the title of the question to what OP intended to ask. *"Will both the cout statement always print the same value?"*

Comment: _Can a pointer returned by new have the same value as a deleted pointer returned by a previous use of new_ Yes.  _Will both the `cout` statement always print the same value?_ Not necessarily.  Certainly, don't rely on it.

Comment: @JasonLiam it is improved, but subtly changes the question, it is no longer about different types.  I had to modify my answer for it to make sense in the context of your change.

Comment: @Clifford I see. I apologize for the inconvenience. Just want to make the title more clear and inline with what OP is trying to ask.

Comment: @JasonLiam not a problem, I just commented in order that the OP might choose to clarify if somehow the question is no longer what he intended. The question clearly required improvement!

Answer (score 2):

> Will both the cout statement always print the same value?

No. After the `delete(p)` the memory allocated by the first `new` expression is deallocated and therefore free to be reused for a later evaluation of a `new` expression, but there is no guarantee at all that it will be.

That you are reusing the same pointer variable `p` is irrelevant. It simply stores the address of the storage location returned by the new expressions. You could have used different pointer variables to store the addresses in the same way.

It is also irrelevant that you create a `int` in the first `new` expression and a `int[4]` in the second. Both of the new expressions happen to return a `int*` which can be stored in the same variable, but nothing would change about the above if you had used simply `int` in both, or had used completely different types and a pointer variable of type `void*`.

Comment: I saw a very similar question(that asked if pointer returned by new can have same value). That question was asked in the last 6-7 months. For the moment, i couldn't find that question. Maybe you answered that question in the past. Or it got deleted.

Comment: @JasonLiam Could be, but I don't think I would remember it. But it doesn't seem unlikely that there is a suitable duplicate. I just feel it is difficult to find good ones with decent answers for this type of question (probably because they often get deleted).

Answer (score 0):

> Will both the cout statement always print the same value?

No. The purpose of `delete` is to allow memory to be reused so it's possible that the next allocation returns a value just deleted.

But how `new` manages memory is unspecified.
For example it my be managing pools of different sizes so asking for space 4 integers may not be from the same pool as 1.

It may be that on your platform that simple program will always return the same value twice. But you should regard that as entirely incidental and not something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst in this simple case you may observe the same address assigned to `p` that is not generally the case.  The allocator will allocate a block of memory on a first fit basis, and it is likely in this case that the first available block of the requisite size will be at the same address as the block just released.

If you were to change the example to:

```
delete(p);
volatile int* dp = new int[4] ;
p = new int[4];
cout<<p;
```

You will almost certainly observe that the pointer value of `p` is no longer the same.   Moreover if you were to have:

```
int* p1 = new int[4] ;
int* p = new int[4];
int* p2 = new int[4];
cout << p1;
cout << p2 ;
cout << p ;
delete[] p ;
p = new int[Ox8000];
cout << p;
```

It is likely that the heap will be fragmented such that the second `p` allocation will not fit in the space released by the `delete`.

The `delete` does not remove the memory from existence, it rather marks the block as available for re-use, returning it to the heap (and coelesing it with adjacent free memory). What you are observing when you get the same pointer value is simple reuse of the space returned to the heap.

Comment: The compiler is likely to optimize away the allocations for `dp`, `p1` and `p2` (at least if optimizations are enabled). So it is still likely to print the same addresses.

Comment: @user17732522 : point taken, modified tests.